# How to assign Text to A file upload control on an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, controls

My file upload control is in page for editing records so i want to retrieve the path stored in database and assign it file upload control.
i have written select query to get data but i do not know how to display the stored file path in file upload control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cannot Assign Text to file Upload control it is read only control.

Comment: It is a security thing. If you could assign text, you could upload any known user file, without user's approval.